# What would a category product with a single object instead of two objects be?

Tags: category-theory

In my attempt to get an intuition over the definition of the category product:

[image]

particulary over the uniqueness requirement of *f* (now I kind of see that if there can be many *f* then the product object is "too big" and if there's no *f* the product would be "too small"), and since according to Wikipedia there can be products with more than two objects, I tried to make it simpler to myself by considering a product with a single object:

[image]

So in this case, the definition would be that for every *f₁* there is an *f* such that *g∘ f* = *f₁*. It seems to me that if this is the case then *g* would be a kind of isomorphism, and I think that if *g* actually is an isomorphism then there will always be a single *f* meeting the requirements (by doing *g⁻¹∘ f₁*), but I'm not sure this implication also goes the other way.

So my question is, what would this tell us about *g*? Is this a thing in category theory?

Comment: Yes that right : in any categories, the product of the single object $X_1$ is any object $X$ with an isomorphism $g:X\to X_1$. So we usually take $X$ to be $X_1$ itself and $g$ to be the identity : the product of the single object $X_1$ is $X_1$ itself. It is not that surprising right ?

Comment: @Roland: But then would that imply that it is an isomorphism? Can this be easily shown?

Comment: Yes $g$ must be an isomorphism. This can easily be shown using the standard proof with universal properties. First with $Y=X_1$ and $f_1:Y\to X_1$ the identity, the universal property yields a morphism $u$ such that $gu=\operatorname{id}_{X_1}$. Second, with $Y=X$ and $f_1=g$, you can check that both $ug$ and $\operatorname{id}_X$ are candidate for $f$. By uniqueness $ug=\operatorname{id}_X$. So $g$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think about what the product of one thing means typically: if I were to write
$\prod_{i=1}^1 x_i$, I'm multiplying all $1$ of the $x_i$s together, and I end up with just $x_1$. So, before thinking too hard we might guess that $X_1 \times = X_1$, or at least isomorphic.

Secondly, recall that the definition of a product actually involves three things: $X_1 \times X_2$, and the two projections $g_1: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_1$ and $g_2: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_2$. So, the definition of a 1-product should involve two things: $X_1 \times$ and $g: X_1 \times \to X$.

Finally, we hope that $g$ is an isomorphism between the two objects, so let's try to show this.  First, use $Y=X$ and $f_1$ as the identity map to construct $h$ which satisfies $\mathrm{id}_X = g \circ h$.

Now, use $Y = X\times$ and $f_1$ as the map $g: X \times \to X$ giving there is a unique $p: X \times \to X \times$ such that $g = g \circ p$. But note that $g = g \circ \mathrm{id}_{X\times}$ and $g \circ (h \circ g) = g \circ h \circ g = \mathrm{id}_X \circ g = g$, so we must have that $h \circ g = \mathrm{id}_{X\times}$ by uniqueness.

Thus, $g$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: OK I think I get it now. What I described is really just the definition of a monomorphism, which is not the same as an isomorphism (I think iso implies mono but not the other way around?). Would this be correct?

Comment: @Juan I've edited my post - I had a proof of mono but I've written a proof of iso instead. That said, you're correct that monomorphism doesn't imply isomorphism, but in this case it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that an isomorphism gives the product of a single object, for the reason you described. The implication goes the other way (in the sense that if a map $g$ satisfies this universal property, it must be an isomorphism). This is a consequence of a very general fact about universal properties: if you have two different objects with morphisms satisfying a universal property, there is a unique isomorphism between them that respects these morphisms.

To see how this works out in your example, you know that there is a product of $X_1$ given by $X_1$ itself, with $g:X_1\to X_1$ the identity map. Now suppose that $g':Z\to X_1$ is another product of $X_1$. Because $X_1$ and $g$ satisfy the universal property, there is a unique map $f:Z\to X_1$ with $g\circ f = g'$. On the flip side, since $Z$ and $g'$ satisfy the universal property, there is a unique map $f':X_1\to Z$ with $g'\circ f' = g$.

Here we used the "existence" part of the universal property to get two maps $f$ and $f'$. Then we claim $f$ and $f'$ are inverses, which will use the "uniqueness" part. The trick is to use the universal property satisfied by the map $g:X_1\to X_1$ on $g$ itself! This implies that there is a unique map $h:X_1\to X_1$ such that $g\circ h = g$. This could just be the identity map, but by the above, it could also be $f\circ f'$, since $g\circ f\circ f' = g'\circ f' = g$. So by uniqueness, $f\circ f'$ *is* the identity. The same type of reasoning shows $f'\circ f$ is.

So all of the different products are related by unique isomorphisms. In particular, in the case you cite, $g$ is necessarily an isomorphism. This is a general feature of universal properties, which is why we talk about "the" product of some objects -- there may be many products, but they will all be isomorphic in unique ways.